# Keyboard in overlay application

Tags: android, keyboard, overlay

I have an application running on top of the others, it has a fragment with editText. The keyboard appears when you click on editText. But I need her to show up right away. How do I do this? I tried

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_e, container, false);

        manager = (WindowManager) Objects.requireNonNull(App.getContext()).getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                1090,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

        
        rootView = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_e, null);

        manager.addView(rootView, params);

        linearLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.container2);
        enterEt = rootView.findViewById(R.id.enterEt);

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(enterEt, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        enterEt.requestFocus();

        return view;
    }

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterEt"
        style="@style/Text"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_enter"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textSize="@dimen/LargeText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `Activity` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

And to do it programmatically, use this code:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Or add this to your `Fragment` `onCreateView` method:

```
  getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

This is equivalent to the attribute you add to your `manifest`, except that it works only when the `Fragment` is created.

Comment: I don't need it to be visible all the time. Only in the editText fragment

Comment: added the programmatic way.

Comment: Added a third method ;)

Comment: getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);? No, doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: can you give me your code then i will check 
mail me rp1741995@gmail.com